# Sign Out from web site without sign out from social network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, linkedin-api

I have website on `MVC 3` (still). It has ability to log in with some social networks like LinkedIn.

On log Out currently i clear all sessions values.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
Session.Clear();
```

But after this user are redirected to social network site where user saw message "you are logged out" or similar *(tested for LinkedIn)*

How can i make just log off from my site and not from social network site?

Thanks.